# How can i derive the zip code from ip address?

Tags: php

I am trying to add a feature to my website, such that i show his posts based on the zip code he is staying i.e. if a person is coming from new York, ill first show him post only of New York and then show others. For this i want to get the zip code from the ip address.

for example

```
ip addess : 72.229.28.185
```

should return the zip code

```
10001
```

the above is just an example

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454832/any-way-to-get-zip-code-from-ip-address

Comment: check this [linkl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454832/any-way-to-get-zip-code-from-ip-address)

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348614/how-to-determine-a-zip-code-and-city-from-an-ip-address

Answer (score 0):

```
http://api.ipaddresslabs.com/iplocation/v1.8/locateip?key={your "Service Access Key"}&ip={the visitor's IP address}&format={XML/JSON} [&callback={your JavaScript function name}] [&compact={Y/N}]
Example: http://api.ipaddresslabs.com/iplocation/v1.8/locateip?key=ExampleKey123456789&ip=115.113.127.130&format=XML
```